# Testing if a function is uniformly continuous on an open interval

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

> Let $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{4x}\sin\left(\frac{5}{x^2}\right)$, is this uniformly continuous on $(0,2)$?

I started out using the Weierstrass M-Test but quickly realized that this does not apply since I don't have a sequence of functions, which the definitions I read require.  Most of the definitions and rules I see only apply to a sequence of functions.

How else can I test this to see if it is uniformly continuous.

**Edit**

I just realized the Weierstrass M-Test is a test for uniform convergence, not continuity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hints:** use the fact a function continuous on a *compact* interval is continuous.

Now, clearly $(0,2)$ is not compact. But $[0,2]$ is; can $f$ be extended by continuity into a *continuous* function $\tilde{f}\colon[0,2]\mapsto \mathbb{R}$?

And if so, can you derive uniform continuity of $f$ from the uniform continuity of this $\tilde{f}$?

**More details** (spoilers):

> There is no issue at $2$, since $f$ clearly has a limit there. Now, can you show that $f$ admits a limit $\ell$ at $0$? (using, for instance,  that $\sin$ is bounded and $x^{1/3}$ converges to $0$...) There, set $\tilde{f}(0)=\ell$, and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: I don't understand your comment "can $f$ be extended by continuity into a continuous function $f:[0,2] \to \mathbb R$"

Comment: @free_mind "Can you find a continuous function $\tilde{f}\colon[0,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=\tilde{f}(x)$ for all $x\in(0,2)$"?

Comment: So I gather this is uniformly continuous since it is a bounded function times one that approaches $0$.

Comment: More precisely, it is uniformly continuous because it has a limit at both $0$ and $2$ (the former because of what you just said) and therefore can be extended to a continuous function on the compact interval $[0,2]$, which therefore is uniformly continuous. Since $f$ agrees on its domain with that function that is uniformly continuous, it is uniformly continuous.